# How do I turn on verbose logging in the AWS .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, logging, .net-core

If I want to debug something in C# that uses the AWS SDK, the verbose logs will be helpful, but the only documentation I can find involves routing through log4net or System.Diagnostics, which involve complex config files. I just want to print the output to the console.

Answer (score 12):

The clue came from [this bit of the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config.html).

You can just put the following code *before you create any AWS client*, and the verbose logs will be printed to console.

```cs
AWSConfigs.LoggingConfig.LogTo = LoggingOptions.Console;
```